# Multi-sample structural equation modeling: good practices for invariance tests

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

I have a question concerning good practices when testing invariance in multi-sample structural equation models.

I am currently working with a questionnaire which has been administered to three different groups (three countries, in fact). This study includes some single-item measures and some latent variables with 3 or 6 items each. I have tested for invariance using confirmatory factor analyses for the latent variables (each construct separately), obtaining partial scalar invariance in all cases. Ok, good.

Now I am proceeding to test the structural equation models to examine my hypotheses pertaining relationships among variables. Do I keep the loadings and intercepts constrained across groups in this last model? (except for those couple of items that are non-invariant, naturally). Or do I start fresh so to say and keep everything free to vary?

Thank you